# Getting big letter for if query

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a text-based game in batch, where you can type a command to get further in the game. For example, if you type StandUp you will get to the stand up scene.
My problem  is that I have to do every IF query with every word capitalized and not. For example for StandUp, there has to be standup, standUp, StandUp and so on.
This is an easy example with only 4 different versions, but it gets bigger  and bigger. The more different words the command has, the more if queries it gets.

I think you will understand me.

Is there any way to do it different?

Comment: Read the help file for the command you are trying to use before asking a question. **the /I switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string compares.**

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `/I` flag with the `if` command, it does a case-insensitive comparison.

```
REM This goes to standup if the input is StandUp, standup, STANDUP, StAnDuP
REM or any other way of capitalizing the input

if /I "%command%"=="StandUp" goto standup
```